# How to pass order No. from one page to other external php file in Magento?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, magento, include

I am using Magento's **event-observer model** at an event **sales_order_place_after**. From that I catch order No. Then now I want to pass that order no. which is store in a variable to another external php file say **external.php**.
This external.php contains connection to Magento database which fetches data based on **Order No.** so I want to pass this order No. to that query & also I have to include this external.php file in that Observer.php 
so my ultimate aim is that once customer press **Place Order** tab, external.php file must get executed as it will get order No. & it fires query on database & do the needful job.

So plz help me to pass variable from one page to other external.php & also how to include/execute that external.php file at customer place order event(sales_order_place_after)..

My Observer.php-:

```
    <?php   
include("connection/Final/external.php");      
class Sample_Event_Model_Observer {      
public function Mytestmethod($observer) {          
$event = $observer->getEvent();  //Fetches the current event         
$eventmsg = "Current Event Triggered : <I>" . $event->getName() . "</I>";         
echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($eventmsg);     
$Id = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();        
$incrementid = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();      
$ordermsg1 = "Current order Id : <I>" . $Id . "</I>";         
echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($ordermsg1);     
$ordermsg2 = "Current increment Id : <I>" . $incrementid . "</I>";         
echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($ordermsg2);      
$p = new testDatabase();          
$p -> setId($incrementid);         
$p -> dbConnect();       
} } ?>
```

My external.php-:

```
<?php  class testDatabase  {      
public function setId($getId)     
{         
$incrementid=$getId;         
echo $incrementid;     
}      
public function dbConnect()      {               
$db_name = "magento";                 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "magento", "password");          
If (!$con)         {             
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());         }             
$seldb = mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);         
If ($seldb)          {             
echo "Database Found ";             
$query = "INSERT INTO sample(id) VALUES($incrementid)" ;             
$result = mysql_query($query);             
print "id is added to the database";              
mysql_close($seldb);        
 }         else          {             
echo "Database NOT Found ";       
  }   
  } }
```

How can I access variable $incrementid in Function1.php? So problem is I am unable to access $incrementid as it is unable to insert in my sample table. I have catched sales_order_place_after event. So that once customer press PLACE ORDER, I can include Function1.php & it will take increment/order id & I can able to access Functions in it that will do needful job...

My updated files-:
http://www.sample.com/magento/app/code/local/Sample/Event/Model/Observer.php
**Observer.php**

```
<?php

class Sample_Event_Model_Observer {

    public function Mytestmethod($observer) {

    $Id = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();   
    $incrementid = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();

        $cURL = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.sample.com/magento/connection/Final/external.php?order_id=<?php echo $incrementid ?>"); 
        curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
        curl_exec($cURL); 
        curl_close($cURL);  

    }
}
?>
```

Path-: http://www.sample.com/magento/connection/Final/external.php

**external.php**

```
<?php 
    echo "Hi";
    $orderID = $_GET['incrementid']; 
    echo $orderID;  
?>
```

I need to use this value of $orderID variable in below function? HOw to do the same?
Plaese help me...

Answer (score 0):

Using **curl** you can do this

```
$data => array('data'); // array of your data

$ExternalLibPath => 'your extenal file page';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$passsword");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ExternalLibPath);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: HI, My data is not in array , it's in Variable. Does it work in that case? Also what value should I enter at CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$passsword",CURLOPT_URL etc. in all that places. Actually I need not to display data. I just wanted to take Order Id from one file & pass it to external.php file so that it will execute query based on Order No. I just wanted to insert data in table after customer places order on that particular event?

Comment: you can make your variable as array. don't worry about username and password if your host doesn't password producted.Yes you can do work using posted value. if you echo anything in external file you will get the output otherwise just leave that part.

Comment: Hi Gowri, I just wanted to pass order No. to external.php file. I don't wish to show that content on webpage. I added my code above. Please check that & tell me what exactly I need to do. If u put sample code that is better for understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So simple... You can use GET method in `external.php`.

In observer page

```
$cURL = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/external.php?order_id=<?php echo $orderId ?>");
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);
```

In `external.php`, you can get variable value by GET method which we sent it by URL parameter.

```
$orderID = $_GET['order_id'];
```

Comment: HI Oguz, I tried your solution but that didn't work for me. I added my code above. Please check that & let me know what I need to do as I don't wish to show content on webpage for external.php as that require just order No. to execute queries in it.

Comment: Prat, did you call curl function in observer page? if you aren't call, how function will handle necessary things?

Comment: Hi Oguz, Can u plz check my code. I added updated code as per your solution.

Comment: Prat, what happen when you tried above code? Did you get any message?

Comment: HI Oguz, If I run external.php , I get o/p as Hi which is my 1st statement...but no order id in o/p. & Observer.php is Magento's event-observer model which runs fine & catch order id. I don't understand why Order id is not echoed by external.php .

Comment: Put an echo statement in orbserver.php for order id and let see what is going there.